# window.open not opening window

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I'm trying to open a page in a popup as opposed to new tab - but whichever browser I try this simply opens in a new tab, not popup.

```
<input type="button" value="new win" onclick="window.open('http://yahoo.com', 'width=500, height=400')"  />
```

Any reason why?

Comment: I think that what you're facing is due to the fact that modern browsers are configured to open popups in new tabs...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Second parameter must be the window name:

```
<input type="button" value="new win" 
    onclick="window.open('http://yahoo.com', 'mywindow', 'width=500, height=400')"  />
```

Working fine in Chrome and Firefox:

http://jsfiddle.net/DvMy5/2/

Comment: Aaaaargh!! Schoolboy error! Thanks so much - will accept as soon as it lets me

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter should be name..Something like `windowname`

```
<input type="button" value="new win" 
onclick="window.open('http://yahoo.com','windowname', 'width=500, height=400')"  />
```

Answer (score 2):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jams/L7QME/)

```
onclick="window.open('http://yahoo.com', 'MyYahoo', 'width=500, height=400, toolbar=no, menubar=no')"  />
```

`window.open` method is as follow.

```
window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)
```

Here is a good read [Window open() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

> name  Optional. Specifies the target attribute or the name of the
>   window. The following values are supported:

```
_blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default
_parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
_self - URL replaces the current page
_top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded
name - The name of the window
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the 3rd argument to window.open. When you pass the 3rd argument, the browser will open a new window provided the window name(second argument is not already opened).
`window.open("http://localhost:5000", "newWindow", "resizable")`will open window but `window.open("http://localhost:5000", "newWindow")` will open a tab.

Comment: That's true. The syntax is: window.open(URL, name, specs, replace).
To answer the question, the second argument (name) was missing, so adding a blank name solves that: window.open('http://yahoo.com', '','width=500, height=400');

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this something controlled by the various browsers? Using target="_blank" opens in a new tab in Chrome, and my guess is that this also apply for Firefox, Opera, Safari and IE.

Comment: That guess is indeed right. But I think that only applies to `<a />` elements.